# VBA showing error : method 'default' of object 'range' failed

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

```
Sub sec()    
    N = Range("B5")
    c = 0    

    Do While Cells(5, c + 3) <> " "   
        c = c + 1   
    Loop

    For i = 1 To c   
        N = N + Cells(5, i + 2) / (1 + Range("A5")) ^ i    
    Next

    Range("G8") = N    
End Sub
```

I was trying to find the NPV of a series of cashflow but the error message keeps popping up.

Comment: Can you give us testing data to work with? When I declare N/c/i as Long and have for example B5 to L5 having the value 15 with M5 " ", I get a result of 165 without an error.

Comment: Please use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table from Excel and edit it into your question.

Comment: Welcome Rohit! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!